# How to unit test an Angular @Input's setters and getters

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

How could I get the unit test coverage for a component `@Input` that is an object stringify using a setter and getter. The code is working fine, the thing is I can't get fully unit test coverage.

The selector looks like:

```html
<products-list [products]="{"name": "Testing Name", "value": "TN", "isRequired": false}"></products-list>
```

Component:

```ts
private _products: any;

@Input('products')
set products(list: string) {
   this._products = JSON.parse(list);
}
get products() {
   return this._products;
}
```

Comment: What are your current tests? What does the component do with the array? The public interface of your component is just that it takes a string input, which is presumably being used somewhere once it's parsed; you shouldn't need to directly test the getter and setter, as that's an implementation detail.

Comment: If I call the property directly from my test the set function gets coverage but not the get, so taking your answer right, I shouldn't test the get function.

Answer (score 0):

For write test cases of set and get method use async()

```
it('should call', async(()=>{
component.products = [];  // list
expect(component._products).toEqual([]);
}));
```

Try this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

See the following stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-jq4bdj

Notice that test case executes the getter [see console log]